# Persist function scope variable values across callback invocations

Tags: lua, callback, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using the `cron` module of NodeMCU to schedule some things. However I also want an additional feature to be able to schedule on the basis of years and also to run the callback only when the current time is in between the desired date range.

For the above to work I need to persist the date range values inside the callback to make checks, however Lua doesn't seem to persist function scope variables between invocations.

Here is an example code which I uploaded to ESP-12F using ESPlorer:

```
> outervar = 1
> cron.schedule("* * * * *", function(e)
                     local innervar = outervar
                     if innervar == 1 then
                           print("Every minute")
                     end
                 end)
> Every minute
> Every minute
> outervar=0
>
```

I let `Every minute` print for 2 times (i.e the schedule worked for 2 invocations) but as soon as I made `outervar=0` it stopped which means `outervar` got propagated to `innervar`.

I need to persist values of `innervar` across callback invocations. Any help is appreciated. In short I need functionality similar to local (function scope) static variables in C.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do
   local innervar = outervar

   function sched_callback(e)
      if innervar == 1 then
         print("Every minute")
      end
   end
end

cron.schedule("* * * * *", sched_callback)
```

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff .. I see that you have used immediately invoked functions like in JS and you are returning a function object which gets called immediately. But I'm just wondering every time we return the function, how will it preserve the `innervar` value irrespective of `outervar`. I think on every schedule/every minute it will assign `outervar` to `innervar` again right? Will `innervar` still have value as 1 even if `outervar` is changed to to 0 outside. Also I'll try it out on my ESP now and can you add a bit of explanation please? and Upvoted too :)

Comment: Code modified to be more understandable and to preserve `innervar` value between different `cron.schedule` invocations (callback function may be reusable by multiple schedules).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted. I don't want re-usability of callback function across different `cron.schedule`. I want to persist `innervar` value when `sched_callback` is called multiple times. Even if `outervar` changes outside I don't want `innervar` value to change for the callback.

Comment: `innervar` gets initialized only once - before creation of function `sched_callback`, it is not being modified inside `sched_callback` (unless you explicitly make such modification)